# Eigenvalue calculation.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am getting confused by this simple eigenvalue calculation.

> Calculate the eigenvalues of $\begin{bmatrix} 5 & -2\\ 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}$.

Firstly, I row reduce it, to go from $\begin{bmatrix} 5 & -2\\ 1 & 2\end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix} 6 & 0\\ 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}$ by performing $R_1 \to R_1 + R_2$.

The resulting equation is $(6 - \lambda)(2 - \lambda) = 0$ so the eigenvalues should be $6$ and $2$, but I check on wolfram alpha and it says they are $4$ and $3$.

Can someone please explain?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that row reducing won't change the eigenvalues, but it does. You need solve the system from the get go.

Comment: I thought row reducing merely simplifies the matrix, I guess not. Ok I see how it works now. Thanks.

Comment: Clay, if you see how it works, post an answer to the question --- it's actually encouraged here to post answers to your own questions. Then, some time later, you can accept your own answer.

Comment: @Clay No problem. I recommend that you type a simple answer stating the eigenvalues you got and accept it so this question doesn't show as unanswered. Note however that you'll need to wait 48 hours to accept your own answer.

Comment: Okay I posted my answer, thanks for the help everyone, this cleared a lot of things up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An eigenvalue of the $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is a number $\lambda$ such that there is a nonzero vector $v$ with
$$
Av=\lambda v.
$$
Depending on the context you may be looking for $\lambda$ in the real or complex numbers. In any case, the equation is equivalent to
$$
(A-\lambda I)v=0
$$
where $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix. This has a nonzero solution if and only if the rank of $A-\lambda I$ is less than $n$ or, equivalently,
$$
\det(A-\lambda I)=0.
$$
It turns out that the expression $\det(A-\lambda I)$ is a polynomial in $\lambda$ of degree exactly $n$, called the *characteristic polynomial* of $A$. Its roots are precisely the eigenvalues of $A$.

It's *not* possible to use row-reduction for finding eigenvalues. Computing the roots of the characteristic polynomial is not the only way: in some special cases other methods are available. Nevertheless, this method is *always* available.

In your case
$$
A-\lambda I=
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & -2 \\
1 &  2
\end{bmatrix}
-
\lambda
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so the characteristic polynomial is
$$
\det(A-\lambda I)=\det
\begin{bmatrix}
5-\lambda & -2 \\
1 & 2 - \lambda
\end{bmatrix}
=(5-\lambda)(2-\lambda)+2=\lambda^2-7\lambda+12
$$
and the roots are easily computed to be $3$ and $4$.

Comment: Excellent response.

Answer (score 2):

$\det \left(\begin{bmatrix} 5 -\lambda & -2\\ 1 & 2-\lambda\end{bmatrix}\right)=0$
therefore,

$(5 - \lambda)(2 - \lambda) - (-2 \times 1) = 0$

$(5 - \lambda)(2 - \lambda) = -2$

Solving that gives $\lambda\in \{4,3\}$.

Comment: How are you making the matrices look so good?

Comment: It's called mathjax, although I simply call it $\LaTeX$. Click on the edit button, you'll see the code I used to make it look the way they do. In the mean time I'll find you a link so you can learn how to do this. It might look though, but you'll get the hang of it in no time, it's easy, just pratice.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @GitGud I know it's been 3 years but thanks

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Characteristic equation of any $2\times 2$ matrix is given by $\alpha^{2}-S_{1}\alpha+S_{2}=0$
, where $S_{1}=$ sum of principle diagonal element and $S_{2}=$ determinant of given matrix, 
using this we can easily get eigen values of matrix.
So, here we have,
$$\alpha^{2}-7\alpha+12=0$$
$$\Rightarrow (\alpha-4)(\alpha-3)=0$$
$$\therefore \alpha =3, 4 .$$

Comment: Judging by the question, I'd say the OP isn't aware that the characteris polynomial will be what you imediately say it will be. I suggest adding a note beforehand saying something like *the characteristic polynomial is ...*